# Can you find the formula of this function?

Tags: functions

[image]

I tried with the form y=ax+b and $$y=ax^2+bx+c$$ but these forms weren't appropriate for it.

Comment: why don't you use a cubic equation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you notice anything that the numbers in the $y$ column have in common?

> They're all powers of two!

With that information, see if you can play around with the general form for those numbers and get your desired function.  (Hint: you might need to apply a horizontal shift.)

**Answer below**

> $$y=2^{x-1}$$

Answer (score 4):

$$y=\frac{x^3-3x^2+8x}{6}$$

Seriously though, unless you define the family of solutions there are infinite number of functions that would match these 4 requirements.

Answer (score 3):

The solution is not unique.

Here's one solution:

$y = \begin{cases}
2 & : x = 2 \\
4 & : x = 3 \\
8 & : x = 4 \\
x^2 & : \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$

Answer (score 2):

Really, this is secretly a problem that is less about *math* and more about the *language we use to talk about math*.

You're supposed to recognize these numbers as being terms from a familiar sequence of numbers, and then write down a formula general term of that sequence of numbers, adjusted to line up with the inputs.

I say this is mainly about language, because people find it more convenient to write out a few terms of a sequence than writing down the general term, so for effective communication, people expect to be able to write $1,4,9,16,25,\ldots$, and you'll know they're talking about sequence of squares of positive integers. And even when you're just writing for yourself, some people find it more convenient to write this way than to puzzle out a general formula.

Thus, you can't *really* do this problem as it was *intended* without recognizing that $1,2,4,8$ is a sequence of numbers you have memorized.

(okay, this isn't entirely "non-math", because it is a useful skill in math to recognize familiar simple patterns, which lets you conjecture what a general term might be)

---

Now, ignoring the problem as intended and just looking for a formula that fits the data, your idea to try polynomials is a good one. However, the data gives you four equations, so to guarantee a solution for the coefficients, you need four unknowns: i.e. you need a cubic equation.

Most other function forms involving 4 unknown variables could be solved to give a formula as well.

A different piece of analysis you might have tried is writing down the sequence you get by subtracting consecutive terms. Or the quotient of consecutive terms. Or other similar things.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered $y =an^{x-b}$?